# Acknowledge/ignore a nagios alert for X min/hrs/days?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have a Nagios service which has correctly noticed a problem. I am running a command on that machine that will fix that problem. However it will take a few hours to run. Until then it is still (correct) detected by Nagios as a problem. I can "acknowledge" the problem and I won't get notifications again, but if there is a problem with my clean up command, I won't know about it unless I remember to recheck.

Is there anyway to "acknowledge" a nagios problem for a certain amount of time? And after that time, if it's still a problem, to send a nagios alert as per normal? Sort of a "Ignore this problem for the next X mins/hours/days"? a "snooze" button for a nagios problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's called [downtime](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/downtime.html). To quote from the documentation:

> When a host or service is in a period of scheduled downtime, Nagios
>   Core will not allow normal notifications to be sent out for the host
>   or service. However, a "DOWNTIMESTART" notification will get sent out
>   for the host or service, which will serve to put any admins on notice
>   that they won't receive upcoming problem alerts.
>
> When the scheduled downtime is over, Nagios Core will allow normal
>   notifications to be sent out for the host or service again. A
>   "DOWNTIMEEND" notification will get sent out notifying admins that the
>   scheduled downtime is over, and they will start receiving normal
>   alerts again.

There are two variants of downtime:

- *Fixed* downtimes start and end at the exact times you specify
- *Flexible* downtimes start as soon as the service enters a failed state (but after the specified start time) and last for a fixed *duration* (but not longer than the specified end time)

In this case you would want a fixed downtime with start time now and end time the expected completion of your command.